# How do I set the <base> element for a grunt build?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

The final app I'm building will live at /subdirectory on a server.

Setting html5mode to true for angularjs so I lose the # sign works fine. But I also need to set

```
<base href="/subdirectory/"></base>
```

During development, I can't have the 'base' element set as when I run **grunt serve** the server cannot find most of the files.

What is the best way to develop and then maybe set the 'base' element when I do a **grunt build** ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I used the grunt task `usemin`:

**index.html**

```
<!-- build:base /subdirectory/ -->
<base href="">
<!-- endbuild -->
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
usemin: {
    html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
    css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
    options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>'],
        blockReplacements: {
            base: function (block) {
                return ['<base href="', block.dest, '">'].join('');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically I defined a custom build block named `base` and this way it's using "" during development (or whatever you set there) and for production the value from the build block config.

Answer (score 0):

Please [read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1889076/is-it-recommended-to-use-the-base-html-tag). I avoid using base tag. To solve the problem you have (which I also had) please do two things:

1. In index.html specify all js/css path as relation to index.html path, so it works in both prod/dev
2. write an http interceptor which while loading html/api calls append the base to the url

   ```
   myapp.factory('MyHttpInterceptor',[ "$log", function ($log) {

       var requestInterceptor = function (config) {
           var prefix = document.location.pathname.substring(0, document.location.pathname.length - 1);
           if (config.url.indexOf(".html") !== -1) {
               config.url = prefix + config.url;
           }
           if (config.url.indexOf("/api/") !== -1) {
               config.url = prefix + config.url;
           }
           return config || $q.when(config);
       };

       return {
           request: requestInterceptor,
       };
   }
     ]);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Use in inside  head tag `<base href="/your MainDomain Name">`

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

  <base href="/your MainDomain Name">
</head>
```

Comment: Yes thanks I understand where to put the 'base' tag. I just cannot have it there during development as running grunt serve then fails to load the app.

Comment: @magician11 Can you please help me in resolving this? I am unable to add the following in my index.html at dist folder : <base href="/"> after <head> tag